Conkies don't show curves
When I install a conky with curvature no matter what, I just see the text and straght lines. No circle, no curvature. I have an arch linux with conky-lua-nv installed and wayland. I have been able to see curves on this mchine before but after changing OS this problem happened.
arch linux 6.9.8-arch1-1

plasmashell 6.1.2

conky 1.21.3-pre-bba3fe0 compiled for Linux x86_64

Compiled in features:

System config file: /etc/conky/conky.conf
Package library path: /usr/lib/conky


 General:
  * math
  * hddtemp
  * portmon
  * IPv6
  * Curl
  * RSS
  * wireless
  * support for IBM/Lenovo notebooks
  * nvidia
  * builtin default configuration
  * old configuration syntax
  * Imlib2
  * OSS mixer support
  * apcupsd
  * iostats
  * ncurses
  * Internationalization support
  * PulseAudio

 Lua bindings:
  * Cairo
  * Imlib2
  * RSVG
 X11:
  * Xdamage extension
  * Xinerama extension (virtual display)
  * Xshape extension (click through)
  * XDBE (double buffer extension)
  * Xft
  * ARGB visual
  * Own window
  * Mouse events
 Wayland:
  * ARGB visual
  * Mouse events

 Music detection:
  * CMUS
  * MPD
  * MOC

 Default values:
  * Netdevice: eno1
  * Local configfile: $HOME/.conkyrc
  * Localedir: /usr/share/locale
  * Maximum netdevices: 256
  * Maximum text size: 16384
  * Size text buffer: 256

Lua 5.4.7  Copyright (C) 1994-2024 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

Any idea?
